# IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware - Unhandled exception: Keyset does not exist

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, x509certificate

My system is throwing the following error "Keyset does not exist"

This error happened to me after updating the sdks and verions of netCore in my PC. My project was updated to use .NetCore 2.2 and all nuggets were updated too.
[image: PowerShell DotNet Versions]

What is weird here is that, I rolled back to a previous version of my project where everything is fine, is in production, all nuggets are still in previous versions where everything worked fine. It works fine except in my computer.

Already read every single page related to this topic, re-installed the certificate, gave permissions to every single user using MMC/Manage private keys. Every single user there has "Full Control"
[image: MMC - Local Computer]

As said before, it happened suddenly, nothing of this was needed before, only had to install the certificate using mmc...

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(GlobalConfig.CertificateOptions.Path, GlobalConfig.CertificateOptions.Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

builder.AddSigningCredential(cert);

services.AddDataProtection()
         .PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()
         .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(cert);
```

Had this code working before. Now it was throwing the following error when trying to authenticate the user

`_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, vm.Password, vm.RememberLogin, false);`

```
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#  >>>>MIDDLEWARE: Caught exception: Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__61_0(CspParameters csp)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.EncryptedXmlDecryptor.EncryptedXmlWithCertificateKeys.GetKeyFromCert(EncryptedKey encryptedKey, KeyInfoX509Data keyInfo)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.EncryptedXmlDecryptor.EncryptedXmlWithCertificateKeys.DecryptEncryptedKey(EncryptedKey encryptedKey)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, String symmetricAlgorithmUri)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.DecryptDocument()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.EncryptedXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngGcmAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory.CreateEncryptorInstance(IKey key)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.CreateEncryptor()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRing.KeyHolder.GetEncryptorInstance(Boolean& isRevoked)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRing.get_DefaultAuthenticatedEncryptor()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data, String purpose)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleSignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, String authenticationMethod)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(TUser user, Boolean isPersistent, String loginProvider, Boolean bypassTwoFactor)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at OneLogin.Managers.AccountManager.SignIn(UserSignInInputModel vm) in D:\BobBA\_work\7\s\src\OneLogin.Managers\AccountManager.cs:line 117
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at OneIdentity.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn(UserSignInInputModel signInModel) in D:\BobBA\_work\7\s\src\OneIdentity\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 236
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Collab.RestAPI.Middleware.HttpExceptionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
08:33:56.413 I      9 32764 1000 #default#     at Collab.RestAPI.Middleware.ErrorHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

After that error I commented the line "services.AddDataProtection()..." and "PasswordSignInAsync" is now working. However i'm still **can't request Tokens using the /connect/token endpoint**. It throws now the following error

```
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#    "ClientId": "mvc",
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#    "ClientName": "MVC Client",
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#    "GrantType": "client_credentials",
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#    "Scopes": "mvc_test",
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#    "Raw": {
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#      "client_id": "mvc",
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#      "client_secret": "***REDACTED***",
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#      "scope": "mvc_test"
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#    }
10:19:55.669 I     21 32766 1000 #default#  }
10:19:55.819 E     21 32766 1000 #default#  [IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware] Unhandled exception: Keyset does not exist
10:19:55.824 E     21 32765 1000 #default#  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel] Connection id "0HLOK0NLHCJ2B", Request id "0HLOK0NLHCJ2B:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `X509Certificate2 cert` is not null at runtime? It also needs to be at least 2048 bit key.

Comment: Hi @VidmantasBlazevicius. Yes i already debugged those simple things =) It was working before with the same certificate

Comment: any solution for that? i just moved my net5 aspnet core to new server and am trying to host it in iis.. got `Keyset does not exist`